# redirect only domain.com to domain.com/subfolder/index.php not domain/whatever

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, oxwall

If user request existing php code, which I placed right in the root:

- domain.com/images/pic1.jpg
- domain.com/anyphp.php
- domain.com/someapp/somecode.php
- domain.com/anything.someExt
- etc

don't do anything,leave as it, they are working good.

But if he simply enter domain.com -> send him to domain.com/myNewApp/index.php, which is my cool new app. Don't rewrite the URL to domain.com/index.php because it is for my existing app.

I expect the answer may be super simple but I am just giving up trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectoryIndex oxwall/index.php

Simple but it works

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the Apache conf file? If so:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/myNewApp/index.php
```

Should work.

**Edit**: This rewrite won't work. I never used the regex-capture. And I misread what you wanted. It looks like you found an answer, but this should still work if you change the regex to:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://example.com/myNewApp/index.php
```

Check out this page for more re-writey goodness:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Thanks, but it is a redirect loop. Everything go to http://domain.com/myNewApp/index.php